# What does the operator #:: mean?

Tags: scala

I realise this is probably a simple question but what is '#::' achieving in below line of code. Is it a special variance of cons ?

```
def from(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n + 1)
```

Comment: You must be taking the Functional Programming in Scala class. I agree with Pere answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This operator is used to construct [streams](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) as opposed to lists. Consider the same code snippet with simple cons:

```
def from(n: Int): List[Int] = n :: from(n + 1)
```

running this method will result in `StackOverflowError`. But with `Stream[Int]` tail is evaluated lazily only when it's needed (and already computed values are remembered).

Comment: because `def` is used the values are not remembered ;)

Comment: @sschaef: true, `val stream = from(0)` would have to be used, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's the equivalent to `::` for Lists, but used with Streams

That is, `n` becomes the **head** of a stream where `from(n+1)` is the **tail**

Answer (score 1):

It means to create a Stream object.

It is identical to `cons` for List -- instead of `::` that always creates a List, `#::` always creates a Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, but there is http://scalex.org/ that is really nice to lockup such things (google is really a mess on anything non-alpha-numeric)! Good Luck!